# Tab-based design for a productpage?

Tags: user-expectation, tabs, users, page, product

Let me sketch what I'm talking about.

I work for a company that sells courses (commercial education-branch). The website contains a productpage per course, and there is a lot of content per course to be displayed. This info contains content regarding what will be learned, who it's for, when you're able to start and what it's going to cost you.

**Q: Is there a more conventional way (and more user-friendly) to display content rather than using tabs to divide the content into pieces?** (based on test results or other data)

Comment: Use of tab, what user expects. 

If you don't want to add tab, you can use accordion.

Comment: Have you looked at approaches from sites with similar challenges? ie Lynda/Treehouse/Rosetta stone etc?

Comment: @Midas The thing with these websites is that they have a very different product, and therefore also a very different approach to their website.

Comment: Oh it will be full of TABS. In case you put in vertical, it will look like this http://sageframe.com/Documentation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any user research to understand what information is important to people related to these courses?

For example, when I go to sign up for a training, I want to know about three things up front.

What does the course cover at a high level? What is the layout for the course content (days and topics)? How much it is going to cost?

I copy and paste this into an email to my manager for approval (with some minor edits).

After that, a nice long pdf with the full description is what I would look for.

Your users could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a single page design rather than splitting the page into tabs? Without knowing much about the content, does this sound suitable?

### Single page

If designed respectfully with sufficient hierarchy then a user could happily scroll and skim your product page until they hit something that stands out. Then happily scroll again to the next piece of stand out info. This way no important info is hidden away in a separate tab.

Employ features such as a jump to link list that is always present so a user can jump to a specific section of the page. This is usually divided on main section titles of the page. Buttons within the main content could even jump up/down the page to a particular section.

Performance wise a very long page with many images and other content can take a toll on load time. Consider lazy loading images as the user scrolls their containers into view. This will reduce annoyance and data usage as images never scrolled into view will never be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The main problem is that there is a lot of content (mainly textual content). The page would become very long, and all simply content, no images, no video's or other visual attributes.